# How to develop a model on a CPU before migrating

Tags: docker, ubuntu-20.04, ipu

I am building a multivariate LSTM to model longitudinal data with pytorch.

I have installed Graphcore pytorch (3.1, which includes poplar and popart) and tools from docker.  Rather than installing an IPU immediately, can I develop the model on the CPU to start with before adding or migrating to an IPU?  When I issue any gc-* command it reports no IPU available, which I know is true!

I generally prefer to run in bare metal [Ubuntu 20.04 LTS AMD 1950X Threadripper] rather than via VMs. Do I need a Graphcore account to do this, so I can sign the licence agreement etc? I guess that is implied in the docker application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [IPUModel](https://docs.graphcore.ai/projects/poplar-api/en/latest/poplar/profiling/IPUModel.html), which will run on the CPU and emulate IPU performance. Some operations (e.g. cycle timings) won't be supported but generally it's a pretty good sandbox.

Depending on which level you are writing your code at you might have to look up how the interfacing is done, Tensorflow for instance requires you to set the target in [environment variables](https://docs.graphcore.ai/projects/tensorflow-user-guide/en/1.2.100/tutorial.html#running-on-the-ipu-model-simulator). As far as I am aware the docker setup requires you to have a physical IPU.